# Синтаксический разбор разбор сложного предложения

Tags: синтаксический-разбор

Четверо учеников начали спорить , и дело чуть было не закончилось дракой.

Answer (score 1):

Грамматические основы:

1. Четверо учеников (подлежащее)/ начали спорить (сказуемое) - это
   первая основа
2. Дело (подлежащее)/ не закончилось (сказуемое) - это
   вторая основа.

Не члены предложения: "и" - союз, "чуть было не" - частица.
Второстепенный член предложения - "дракой" (дополнение).

Comment: Уваж. тов. Ajgy! Не стоит раздавать подсказки без разбору. Здесь же поленились и вопрос сформулировать.